# Pandas DataFrame memory reallocation does not release the old memory and soon results in OOM error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, memory, memory-management

My understanding is that `float64` should occupy twice the memory than `float32`. I am using a pandas DataFrame and when I add float32 columns to it the memory consumption is quite subdued. But, when i add `float64` columns to it, the memory consumption behaves in ways that i cannot wrap my head around

I am using the following code to study the two behaviour:

for `float32`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

narr = np.random.rand(500,1000000)

df = pd.DataFrame(narr)

for c, i in enumerate(df.columns):
    print(c,end='\r')
    df[str(i)+'dummy'] = (df[i].values/df[0].values).astype(np.float32)
```

Below is the memory consumption I recorded every 100th iteration (In GB):

- 0 - 4.29
- 100 - 4.43

- 200 - 4.43
- 300 - 4.43
- 400 - 4.44

- 500 - 4.44

Now, for float64

code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

narr = np.random.rand(500,1000000)

df = pd.DataFrame(narr)

for c, i in enumerate(df.columns):
    print(c,end='\r')
    df[str(i)+'dummy'] = (df[i].values/df[0].values).astype(np.float64)
```

Here the behaviour is weird. At every 100th iteration:

1. The iterations pause for a while
2. The memory consumption shoots up by 5GBs approx
3. The Memory consumption falls down by 1-4 GBs
4. The iterations continue and the Memory consumption remains the same (Steady) for the next 100 iterations
5. The process repeats from step 1

- itr - Steady, Max
- 0 - 4.29, 4.29
- 100 - 8.17, 10.5
- 200 - 11.9, 15.2
- 300 - 15.7, 16.4
- 400 - 19.4, 21.5
- 500 - 23.1, 26.7

Please help me understand:

1. Why is the memory consumption not a simple `float64` = `float32`*2 relationship?
2. Why the weird Memory increment pattern for `float64`? It seems to increase every 100 iterations and there too it first shoots up significantly and falls down slightly and stays there for the next 100 iterations

Edit:
I used df._mgr as suggested in the comments by @hpaulj. It revealed:

1. The pandas combines all the similar dtyped columns in a memory block
2. Each new column added to the DataFrame is added as a separate memory block
3. The max number of memory blocks that pandas can have is 100
4. **Hence, every 100 iterations pandas shuffles the datasets and reallocates the memory and in the process coalesces the memory blocks of similar dtyped blocks together**
5. So, the issue actually is that if the initial dataset created is of dtype `floatx` then adding `floatx` dtyped new columns will result in memory consumption explosion. This would happen because pandas would reallocate the entire old_columns+new_columns a new contiguous block of memory and vacate the earlier heald memory location

I am not able to understand why that is happening though. One would think that once the entire DataFrame has been reallocated then the old memory location that the DataFrame had occupied would be freed but apparently that is not the case.

Is this a typical case of memory leakage? Would be strange if Pandas didn't take care of releasing the old memory.

Also, I still don't understand why, at the time of reallocation at every 100 iterations, the memory consumption shoots up even more than what it finally settles down to. It seems pandas does release some memory but, not all?

All insights are most welcome.

Comment: display `df._mgr` after creating the `df`, and periodically later.  It may give some more insights on how `pandas` is managing the arrays the underlie the frame.  I think initially `df` contains a `view` of the original `float64` array.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj . `df._mgr` method has definitely given a lot of insights. I am updating the question with them. I am still not able to conclude based upon those. I would be grateful if you could give them a look and provide help.